# How to get the path name outside the loop?

Tags: java, image, swing, static, path

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     jButton3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        //String pathName;
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            String pathName = null;
            FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", "jpg", "jpeg");
            fc.setFileFilter(filter);
            int response = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            try {
                if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                     pathName = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                    System.out.println(pathName);      // this works
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pathName);
                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(pathName);
                    jLabel4.setIcon(icon);
                } else {
                    //   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Feel Free to Look Later");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println(pathName);     // THIS DOESNOT
}
```

Comment: 1) For a button, add an `ActionListener` rather than a mouse listener. The button listener will respond to bot mouse and keyboard input. 2) Research 'variable scope' which is a topic that should be clear before approaching an advanced area like making a GUI. 3) OK.. I just noticed (re point (1)) that this code is adding a mouse listener ***inside*** the action performed method of an action listener! That makes no sense. Remove all mention of the mouse listener.

Comment: Why are you adding a `MouseListener` to the button inside it's `ActionListener`?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a field and assign needed value to it:

```
private String pathName;

jButton3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    ....
    pathName = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
    ....
});
System.out.println(pathName);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pathName` variable is created inside the `mouseClicked` function - so it will be destroyed once the function is complete.

You can use it inside the function which is why your first printLn statement works, but it won't exist outside. To fix this, assign the data to a variable that already exists before the function starts so that it continues to exist after the function ends.

Move `String pathName = null;` into a higher scope (like into the class that contains this code snipped) and this will work.